Unable to extract the quantum registers information from qiskit quantum circuit data
Consider the following code:
import qiskit
from qiskit.circuit.random import random_circuit
num_qubits = 3
depth = 1
max_operands = 2
# This limits the circuit to have only single and two qubit gates
qc = random_circuit(num_qubits, depth, max_operands=max_operands, seed=1)
qc = qc.decompose(reps = 3)
for name_of_gate, qargs, cargs in qc.data:
    print("name of gate : ", name_of_gate)
    print("qargs : ", qargs,"\n")

for this I got the following output
name of gate :  Instruction(name='u', num_qubits=1, num_clbits=0, params=[0, 0, 3.141592653589793])
qargs :  [Qubit(QuantumRegister(3, 'q'), 1)] 

name of gate :  Instruction(name='cx', num_qubits=2, num_clbits=0, params=[])
qargs :  [Qubit(QuantumRegister(3, 'q'), 2), Qubit(QuantumRegister(3, 'q'), 0)] 

Now I need to get the quantum register on which a given gate is acting.
Example:
input:
qargs[1]

output:
Qubit(QuantumRegister(3, 'q'), 0)

I somehow need to extract the 0 from Qubit(QuantumRegister(3, 'q'), 0).
I have tried doing the following
input:
qargs[1][1]

output:
TypeError: 'Qubit' object is not subscriptable

input:
qargs[1].register

output:
AttributeError: 'Qubit' object has no attribute 'register'

input:
qargs[1].index

output:
AttributeError: 'Qubit' object has no attribute 'index'


You can use QuantumCircuit.find_bit() method:
print("qargs : ", [qc.find_bit(qarg)[0] for qarg in qargs],"\n")

find_bit() returns a tuple that contains two elements; the first element is the index at which the Bit can be found (in either qubits or clbits according to its type). The second element is a list of (register, index) pairs with an entry for each Register in the circuit which contains the Bit.
